# Does the exterior appearance of Hogwarts really change throughout the series?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, hogwarts

The exterior appearance of Hogwarts castle has a unique and easily recognisable look. [This article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2109071/Incredibly-detailed-model-Hogwarts-Castle-used-Harry-Potter-film-revealed-time.html) is about the incredible detailed model of the castel, that has been used for every film in the series.

[image: Hogwarts caststle model]

While most of it stays the same over the series, there are changes between the movies. Most obvious are the changes between the second and the third movie (a bell tower, a bridge, and more is added). These changes can (maybe) be rationalised by the explanation that in the first parts no scene is taking place near the areas added in later parts.

**Is it theoretically possible, that Hogwarts Castle never changed it's exterior appearance during the movie series?**

I'm not asking about behind the scenes material, as I'm sure they have made changes there. I'm wondering about the audiences point of view. 
Example: Throughout the series we see Hogwarts from a lot of different angles. Let's say in part 4 a new tower appears. The absence of this tower in older movies can be explained by it beeing hidden behind a wall. In this case there was no "real" change. The tower could have existed before, we've just never had a chance to see it.

Comment: Well, the absolutely massive viaduct that magically appears in DH is a bit of a giveaway; http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:New_Hogwarts_for_DH

Comment: @Richard **Because the films are nonsense**? ;-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Magic!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There can be no denying that it has changed, regardless of perspective.

Compare this early design:

[image]

To this later design which is more recognisable:

[image]

To this one which has the added Astronomy Tower:

[image]

The difference between the first one (Philosopher's Stone) and the last (Half Blood Prince) could definitely not be put down to perspective or any other thing other than magic transformations or film-makers having license with the castle (which I do not judge by the way). Even between the 'with and without the Astronomy Tower' castles, I don't see how any angle would shield a tower taller than any other and very recognisable.

Comment: I think you misunderestimate the experience Hollywood have in [hiding offending objects behind scenery items](https://youtu.be/BJG4QyDI620?t=29s)

Comment: @Richard - That's funny. And I do love Bushisms like misunderestimate. My favourite word at the moment is irregardless.

Comment: The reason the 1st image and the 2nd look so different is the 1st is Hogwarts from the back, the second is from the front.

Comment: @RedCaio - Yes but just look at those sort of Russian-looking, squat towers with other towers growing out of them that just do not exist later on. The design and overall style is very different.