# Is the Lego Hogwarts Castle consistent with canon?

Tags: harry-potter, lego

Lego recently released a [beautiful Hogwarts castle](https://shop.lego.com/en-US/product/Hogwarts-Castle-71043).
[image]
[image]

I would love to buy it, but before I do, I need to know: Is it consistent with canon? (Either book or movie).
If not, where does it differ?

Comment: The key difference is that the actual castle is made of stone whereas the Lego one is made of small plastic blocks. Also it's much smaller.

Comment: @Valorum I obviously meant major differences in the floor plan. Also, the lego one is populated by minifigs as opposed to humans.

Comment: [Obligatory meme](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JrKQX.jpg)

Comment: Obviously, the grounds are missing, which include the fields adjacent to the castle, as well as the Quidditch pitch.

Comment: Oh why couldn't you misspell canon! ~ then I could have gone for a long winded explanation of how you'd have to superglue the bricks together to avoid it shaking apart when you fired them from the walls.

Comment: Damn, it even comes with a dragon in one of the towers! I'm jealous, now I also want one :)

Comment: Which movie canon? See [this link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129604/what-changes-have-been-made-to-hogwarts-throughout-the-series) for the changes to Hogwarts throughout the movies... seams like it mostly matches the Prizoner of Ascaban set...

Comment: It is really nice, but it's also kinda more of an ornament really, you can't really play with it that well because standard size lego figures are too big. I genuinely think I prefer the original, although I ran out of ideas pretty quickly as a child i admit .... :P

Comment: I mean, not that I'd say no if you wanted to buy it for me :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the **canonical source** is concerned this Lego set is, like the other smaller minifig-scale Lego models, a **movie** tie-in (a good hint is the *movie font* being used on the box, together with the *Wizarding World logo*).

The (first out of four) [instruction booklet](https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/6252747.pdf) contains interesting information about what the set was meant to be:

> Begin a magical journey with this detailed replica of the iconic HogwartsTM Castle.
>   Explore the prestigious school of witchcraft and wizardry. Experience a microscale LEGO® model built from over 6,000 pieces and packed with authentic details for a rewarding building experience. Discover the intricately designed chambers, towers, classrooms and many other hidden features depicting **scenes from the Harry PotterTM series** and recreate the **movies’ pivotal moments** of magic and adventure.
>   <sub>(page 3, emphasis mine)</sub>
>
> Translating the magical onscreen locations into a LEGO® model in microscale was an exciting design challenge. To represent the **key architectural structures**, **iconic silhouettes** and **details** in tiny bricks, whilst retaining the unforgettable look and feel of the movies, was not an easy task.
>   <sub>(page 4, idem)</sub>

A few pages in, Lego model designer Justin Ramsden states:

> My design approach focused on capturing the essence of Hogwarts; its **iconic silhouette**, the exciting feeling of going back to school and starting a new adventure. I wanted to recreate all the **iconic locations** from the castle and **moments from the movie series** in ‘micro-detail’, including the moving staircases, the Whomping WillowTM, Professor Lupin’s Boggart lesson in the Defence Against the Dark Arts classroom and the Basilisk encounter in the Chamber of Secrets.
>   <sub>(page 6, idem)</sub>

So, concerning the consistency with the source:

- the **esterior face** of the model **in its entirety** aims at recreating the **general silhouette** of movie-Hogwarts as seen from the lake *on a small scale*
- the resulting **interior space** is used to house a collection of places and scenes coming from **all the movies** represented *on a larger scale*, which are therefore inherently incoherent and sometimes "out of place" and not matching the outside, for example

  - the Chamber of Secrets is directly under the Great Hall
  - the Room of Requirements is in the underground level, next to Snape's Potions Classroom (which is in the "right" place)
  - House Gryffindor's Common Room in on the ground floor of the large building on the right of the model, next to the library

Answer (score 1):

This is a picture (from [the Daily Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/travel/Spark/harry-potter-studio-tours/hogwarts-set-warner-bros-studio-tour.jpg?imwidth=1400))  of the model of Hogwarts on display at the Warner Brothers studio tour.

[image]

You can tell right away that the Lego model is incomplete, but a pretty good match from the outside.

So the leftmost building which I believe is the clock tower and behind that the Great Hall? is clearly present in both pictures, and then you've got the courtyard outside the clock tower and the path leading down to the boathouse is even correct. Then you can see the tall tower, which I suppose is the Astronomy tower, and the adjoining building is all correct. The bridge in the foreground is correct, and then that leads into your building which is the rightmost building in the Lego set, but there's a lot more in the real thing. I believe Potions is taught in the dungeons beneath that building.